# User authentication using stored procedure from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication, logging, stored-procedures

I am trying to make a functional site for project management. In my backend code (`aspx.vb`) I try to make a redirecting to the next page using stored procedure for user authentication based in a user username and password. I don't have any errors in my code, but when I execute it, it doesn't go to the next page.

I need advice how to resolve this.

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class LoginPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server=PCOFTOMI\SQLEXPRESS;Database=VodeneProjekta;Integrated Security=true")

    Private WithEvents ButtonLogin As Button
    Public Property TextBoxUserName As Object
    Public Property TextBoxPassword As Object
    Private _Response As Object

    Public Function GetResponse() As Object
        Return _Response
    End Function

    Public Sub SetResponse(AutoPropertyValue As Object)
        _Response = AutoPropertyValue
    End Sub

    Public Property MessageBox As Object

    Private Sub ButtonLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonLogin.Click
        Server.Transfer("NadzornaPloca1.aspx")
        Dim params(2) As SqlParameter

        params(0) = New SqlParameter("@Korisničko_ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        params(0).Value = TextBoxUserName.Text

        params(1) = New SqlParameter("@Zaporka", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        params(1).Value = TextBoxPassword.Text

        params(2) = New SqlParameter("@ValidUser", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        params(2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        Dim command As New SqlCommand()
        command.Connection = connection
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        command.CommandText = "dbo.AuthentifikacijaKorisnika"

        command.Parameters.AddRange(params)

        Try
            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim result As String = command.Parameters("@ValidUser").Value.ToString()

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
                ' Login successful, redirect to another page based on the username
                Select Case TextBoxUserName.Text.ToLower()
                    Case "ivan.ivic"
                        GetResponse().Redirect("NadzornaPloca1.aspx")
                    Case "ana.anic", "marko.markovic"
                        GetResponse().Redirect("NadzornaPloca2.aspx")
                    Case "jasna.jasnic", "igor.igorek", "petra.petrovic", "stjepan.stjepanic", "katarina.katarinovic", "josip.josipovic", "martina.martinovic"
                        GetResponse().Redirect("NadzornaPloca3.aspx")
                    Case Else
                        ' Handle invalid username or show error message
                        MessageBox.Show("Netočno korisničko ime.")
                End Select
            Else
                ' Handle failed login or show error message
                MessageBox.Show("Netočno korisničko ime ili lozinka.")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Handle exceptions, log or show an error message
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I note you're passing the password as a plain text value. I *hope* your procedure is salting and heading that password.

Comment: _I don't have any errors in my code_ Are you sure? Because in the code above I can see an empty try/catch block. If this is really your code then any exception will be hidden by that code and you can't see the error

Comment: Aside... `MessageBox.Show` is very much a desktop application thing. This code is running on the web server, do you expect it to pop a message box on the web server's desktop? Have a read through [Error Handling in ASP.NET Pages and Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/w16865z6(v=vs.100)) to see how you'd do this in the old ASP.NET technology stack.

Comment: Also you are caching the connection object which you shouldn't ever do. Create when needed, dispose with `Using`.

Comment: Please look at storing your [connection string in your web.config file](https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/).

Comment: @Charlieface I had considered pointing out the lack of using, however he does have it wrapped up in a try catch and a finally block. Felt that was at least sufficient.

Comment: Your parameter creation for your SqlCommand object is all over the place as well. You can add them directly to your SqlCommand object like `command.parameters.add("@ParamName", sqldbtype.nvarchar,50).value = yourValue`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so new to this and lots of issues here.

First up, while it can be some work, I suggest starting out with a template that has the logon system "already built" for you. After all, it is "really" common to want and have a logon system for a web site.

However, avoiding the "work" or "pain" to setup and use the built in logon system is tempting and "seems" like less work?

It is not!

So, you REALLY but REALLY should use an existing pre-built logon system and setup. The reasons are many, but bottom line is trying to roll your own logon system and security system for the web is a RATHER large task.

And there are HUGE bonus points for using the asp.net security system. For one, you can secure web pages and do so with ZERO LINES of code! And as a result, you not try to write a whole boatload of security code for each and every web page.

You can and most certainly will often test/check say if a user is some "web site admin" with special abilities, but even in this case, security for those "admin" features and web pages once again is 100% automatic locked down. If a user without correct permission attempts to use any of those pages, they can't and are automatic locked out.

The other issue of course is not only "rolling" your own security system a boatload of work, but after having done all that work, you NEVER really have much of a secure system as compared to the built in system.

Don't try this - just don't. The built in security and logon system will save you a good solid week of work or more, and thus you can spend you time playing and just building some web pages as opposed to spending all your efforts on some logon system which will not be very good anyway.

So, having stated the above, let's clean up your code, and at least get it working as a leaning experience.

You don't show what the stored procedure looks like, but no huge worry.

So, the code you have should thus become much like this:

```
Protected Sub ButtonLogIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonLogIn.Click

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("AuthentifikacijaKorisnika")
    cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    With cmdSQL.Parameters

        .Add("@Korisničko_ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBoxUserName.Text
        .Add("@Zaporka", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBoxUserName.Text

    End With

    Dim rstLogon As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL)

    If rstLogon.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        ' no rows returned, logon fail
        lblMessage.Text = "invalid logon"
        Exit Sub ' 
    End If

    ' if we get here, then logon was matched

    Select Case rstLogon.Rows(0).Item("UserName")
        Case "ivan.ivic"
            Response.Redirect("NadzornaPloca1.aspx")

        Case "ana.anic", "marko.markovic"
            Response.Redirect("NadzornaPloca2.aspx")
        Case "jasna.jasnic", "igor.igorek", "petra.petrovic", "stjepan.stjepanic", "katarina.katarinovic", "josip.josipovic", "martina.martinovic"
            Response.Redirect("NadzornaPloca3.aspx")
        Case Else
            ' valid logon, but not speical case.
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
    End Select


End Sub



Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

So, our logic is that the stored procedure will return one data row with information about the logon. In fact, the record(s) you have for the logon should be used for re-direction to a given page based on say some setting in the user logon table (the hard coding of users you have REALLY BUT REALLY should be removed. It makes no sense to try and code out special cases based on hard coded names in code behind).

Note that since we will "over and over" have to pull data from the database, then it fast becomes tiring to re-write code to pull data over and over. So, in above, you can see the handy "helper" routine I have. It simple returns the SQL query (or stored procedure) as a data table. With that your code can process the results, get all columns, and of course use row count to test if any results were returned. In fact, I recommend you place the MyRstP code stub in a global standard module. Thus, all your code in all pages can use that MyRstP helper code over and over.

As noted, I suggest you try/use/start out with a pre-made template. There are lots of them, but I suggest creating a new project, and selecting say this template options:

[image]

Next, and then you see this page:

[image]

Note the Authentication (logon) option in above.

So, when you create the above, then you have a nice web site, logon code setup, and it starts out with a nice bootstrap "menu bar" as the default setup.

So, you wind up with this:

[image]

So, in above you see a nice pre-built menu bar, and you can see that Register and Logon are already setup for you. So, you can thus now modify the template, maybe remove the register part. But at least you have a nice layout and logon system pre-built, pre-setup, and it will save you that week or more of work.

Comment: Mentioned here by Albert, but most certainly, the select case/switch statement you are using to redirect users needs to go. This means every user that you add will require updates to your solution. You would be well served moving those "starting page" urls into your database and returning them with your query and redirecting from there.